# scp to Windows2012Server running Microsoft's OpenSSH-server port, fails with `Broken pipe`

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-server-2012-r2

Just installed [Microsoft-blessed's OpenSSH Window port](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) and it works great for ssh sessions from Linux clients:

```
andrew@debian:~$ ssh 55.55.55.55
The authenticity of host '55.55.55.55 (55.55.55.55)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:oPx2UbDPJakzpAuiTyMDJI6oDExifs5crCbXIrClgxA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '55.55.55.55' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
andrew@55.55.55.55's password: 
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

andrew@TEST-ADMIN C:\Users\andrew>exit
exit
    Connection to 55.55.55.55 closed.
```

However, if I want to send a file using scp, it fails with:

```
andrew@debian:~$ scp test.fsx 55.55.55.55:c:/users/Andrew
andrew@55.55.55.55's password: 
packet_write_wait: Connection to 55.55.55.55 port 22: Broken pipe
lost connection
andrew@debian:~$
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using [Windows paths](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/62) correctly, so that is not your problem.

However there appears to be currently issues when porting scp subsystem. Quoting from [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/222):

> As for SCP I believe that there have been issues with porting it that
>   have lead to it being removed for the last few releases until they can
>   fix it up.

So I guess your best bet currently is using `sftp`, which is very easy to set up according to the [wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/sftp.exe-examples).

Answer (score 0):

As of now (6/1/2016), the project is still a really early preview. The latest release is even labeled, "This is a pre-release (non-production ready)." I doubt you're going to find much help with it here until it's actually released for production use and more people start using it. You might have more luck opening an issue on the actual Github repo.